# Rails Scope where most recent association is older than 1 month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two models in my app, one called `Feed` and one called `Post`. A feed has many posts.

I am looking for a way to return the feeds where the most recent post is older than 1 month.

I've got something simple like:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  scope :no_recent_posts, -> { includes(:posts).where('posts.created_at > ?', 1.month.ago) }
end
```

but of course this also returns any feeds if they have old posts (even if they have more recent ones too.

Maybe something with a `limit(1`) and an `order`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `GROUP BY...HAVING`.

```
scope :no_recent_posts, { joins(:posts).group(:feed_id).having('max(posts.created_at) > ?', 1.month.ago)
```

Since you don't really need to eager load the posts (based on your requirements), I changed the `includes` to a `joins`.